# What does "nil#" mean in profiler results?

Tags: ruby, profiling

Here is very simplified part of code:

```
srand 0

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 10, 10
array = Array.new(HEIGHT){ [0]*WIDTH }

require "profile"
10000.times do
    y, x = rand(HEIGHT), rand(WIDTH)
    g = array[y][x] + [-1,+1].sample
    array[y][x] = g unless [[y-1,x],[y+1,x],[y,x-1],[y,x+1]].any?{ |y, x|
        y>=0 && y<HEIGHT && x>=0 && x<WIDTH && 1 < (array[y][x] - g).abs
    }
end
```

We see (`ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]`):

```
  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
 39.33     0.86      0.86    47471     0.02     0.05  nil#
```

If we totally remove the `unless` thing:

```
 53.48     0.48      0.48    10000     0.05     0.09  nil#
```

Looks like we get this `nil#` operation:

1. on every **comparision** or **boolean operation**?
2. on every **Array object creation** or **block envocation**?

Would be nice to get a deep answer.

Comment: Comparison of the standard library profiler, versus ruby-prof, for this code. https://gist.github.com/agrimm/a69f7f0f5e238ae2a65b

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, ruby-prof shows higher numbers in `each` and `times`. So the *bottleneck* is in the looping itself ..(